# mysql search for multiple words from multiple textboxes php

Tags: php, mysql

I have form a containing three textboxes and user fills it and clicks on search button it will redirects to another page and display results.. everything was fine.. but the problem is when user enter two words in same text box

(for ex: railway colony)

it will not showing the details..for this I used expolde method to insert "+" symbol for multi word search

here is code

```
 <?php  
     if(isset($_GET["search"]))  
     {  
          $condition = '';  
          $query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);  
          foreach($query as $text)  
          {  
               $condition .= "address LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text)."%' OR   " ;  
          }  
          $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);  
          $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM jposts WHERE " . $condition;  

          $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_query);

          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
          {  
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
               {  
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["address"].'</td></tr>';  
               }  
          }  
          else  
          {  
               echo '<label>Data not Found</label>';  
          }  
     }  
     ?>
```

it works well for one textbox with multiword search..but what about all three textboxes

And my previous query for search is

```
$stmt = $search->runQuery("SELECT * FROM jposts WHERE city LIKE '%".$city."%' 
   AND address LIKE '%".$location."%' AND business_name LIKE 
  '%".$category."%'");
```

i want to implement multiword search for all three textboxes i have

```
for ex: In textbox1 user enters  : tirupati (city)
        In textbox2 user enters  : railway colony (location)
        In textbox3 user enters  : Lic agent (catagory)
```

After clicks search I want to display related info based on above data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the use of urldecode we can remove "+" from get params.

Have a look on mentioned code:

```
if ($_GET) {

  $cityQstr = explode(" ", urldecode($_GET['city']));
  $locationQstr = explode(" ", urldecode($_GET['location']));
  $catagoryQstr = explode(" ", urldecode($_GET['catagory']));

  $condition = [
      $condition . "city LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR city LIKE '%", $cityQstr) . "%'",
      $condition . "address LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR address LIKE '%", $locationQstr) . "%'",
      $condition . "business_name LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR business_name LIKE '%", $catagoryQstr) . "%'"
  ];


  $stmt =  "SELECT * FROM jposts WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $condition);

}
```